# Django Multiple DB, authenticating from NON default db

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two `DATABASES` configured in my Django project:

- `default`
- `reports`

The `reports` database contains `auth_user`, but while authenticating the user, users are checked in the `default` database. How can i use `authenticate()` with the `reports` database?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom database router, as shown in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example) which covers exactly this kind of situation:

```
class AuthRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to reports.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'reports'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to reports.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'reports'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'reports'
        database.
        """
        if db == 'reports':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return False
        return None
```

And you'll need to put the dotted-path to that class into `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in your `settings.py`.

There are [some notes about using Django contrib apps with multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/#behavior-of-contrib-apps) that are worth reading. In particular, as well as the `auth` tables you need the `ContentType` backing table in the same database.

It may be easier to make `reports` your default, and only use the one you're currently calling `default` explicitly, as needed.